# How can I show only the last print in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, flush

There is too much print and I want some of the temporary prints be erased. For example, I have:

```
import time
for shard in range(3):
    for i in range(100):
        print("image_{} in shard_{}".format(i, shard))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Instead of a list of all the prints

```
image_0 in shard_0
image_1 in shard_0
image_2 in shard_0
image_3 in shard_0
```

I want to see them printed once and then be replaced by the next print.

```
image_0 in shard_0
```

```
image_1 in shard_0
```

```
image_2 in shard_0
```

At the end I shall only have

```
image_99 in shard_0
image_99 in shard_1
image_99 in shard_2
```

on the screen.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you expect to only see "World"?

Comment: What do you think `flush` actually does?

Comment: `flush` does not erase stuff already printed. It flushes the buffer.

Comment: Flush is used to forcefuly push the data from buffer to the stream. For more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)

Comment: That isn't what "flush" means.

Comment: sorry for the misleading, I removed flush from the question, please show me how to do the "replacement"

Comment: Related: *[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time
for shard in range(3):
    for i in range(100):
        print("image_{} in shard_{}\r".format(i,shard),end = "")
        time.sleep(1)
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have misunderstood what "flushing the output buffer" means. I doesn't erase what has previously been printed. It just means "print immediately, without waiting for a whole line (or file worth) of output."

An example where flushing can matter is when you print out several things on a single line, with a delay in between them:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(i, end="")
    time.sleep(1)
```

On many consoles this won't print anything for ten seconds, then you'll see `0123456789` appear all at once. But if you add `flush=True` to the `print` call, you'll see each number appear separately, one after the other, with a one second delay in between. You still get `0123456789` on one line, but it builds up gradually. (Note that the consoles built in to some IDEs may not do line buffering in the normal ways a real terminal will, so your mileage may vary. Real consoles are much more consistent.)

If you're printing full lines with a newline at the end (which is the default for `print`), using `flush` usually isn't necessary because most terminals are line-buffered. That means they'll flush themselves automatically at the end of every line, even without `flush=True` explicitly demanding a flush after its output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in range(3):
    print("{}\r".format(i), end="")

print("Hello\r", end="")
print("World\r", end="")
```

The output will be `World`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: as people answered before, `flush` doesnt do what he needs. I gave an alternative, good day

Comment: sorry that's because I changed the question